# SQL Server 2016 is throwing intermittent login failures

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2016

I have a web application using a SQL Server account, and recently started getting intermittent:

`Login failed for user 'xxxx'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`.

- The login works >99% of the time.
- Server is in mixed mode, uses a SQL Server account, and the box is not a member of a domain, and is not part of any farm.
- The password has not been changed for the account since initial
  deployment which occurred months ago and the box has been bounced
  several times since.
- IIS and SQL Server are on the same box.
- TCP is the selected communications method.
- SQL Server 2016
- Windows Server 2012

I have had a problem in the past with a desktop application and connection pooling where if a connection in the pool became invalid for some reason, the app failed when it went to use it. But we got a different errors in that situation.

Before you suggest that a pooling issue is at play, consider the following:
If there were a problem with pooling, why would the connection be attempted at all? Once a connection is in the pool, the connection attempt doesn't show up in the SQL Log, it just gets reused. If the connection was bad, and the application tried to use it, then the application would receive an exception reflecting that problem--the connection doesn't try to log in to the server again.

If this is an effort to spin up a new connection via the pool, why would it succeed the first time, then fail on a subsequent time, and then succeed again? It can't be user error since the connection string is in the web.config.

Here is a picture of the SQL Log entries for the login problem.

Succeeded at 8:47

Failed at 8:58

Succeeded at 9:10

[image: SQL Log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to say that I actually solved the root problem, however the answer to this was to switch to a local NT user account.

After turning off pooling to eliminate it from the equation, I was still getting intermittent login failures using a SQL account, despite it being in the web.config. The app pool was set to never recycle, so I was at a standstill with regard to solving the situation.

Out of desperation I changed the login to use a trusted connection, and everything worked flawlessly. (I haven't turned pooling back on yet.)

Comment: Can you share what you actually did? Steps?

Comment: @Krunal Sorry, I don't understand the context of your question. The errors were a result of real-time usage and could not be reproduced in static testing. If you are asking about the code side of the process it is a MVC app using EF. The app was serving multiple concurrent users with multiple concurrent data sets being generated for page rendering. At any time, the error could appear for any single user in attempting to access any single web page.